How to extract games occurring only once from PGN file(s)?
I am trying to use pgn-extract to extract games that exist exactly once in two PGN files. I thought the following would work:
pgn-extract -U a.pgn b.pgn -o/dev/null -nonly_once.pgn

but it simply removes duplicates like -D would do and keeps the games that occur in both input files.
Is it possible with pgn-extract?

It looks like the following achieves what I need:
(pgn-extract -c a.pgn -D b.pgn; pgn-extract -c b.pgn -D a.pgn) > c.pgn

